# TeamCity REST API build getStartDateTime() returns NULL for a running build

Tags: teamcity

I'm using
`org.jetbrains.teamcity:teamcity-rest-client:1.14.0`

after **TeamCity** server update from 2022.04.3 to **2022.04.4**

```
TeamCityInstanceFactory.guestAuth("my_teamcity_server_url")
.build(new BuildId("id_of_started_but_not_finished_yet_build"))
.getStartDateTime()
```

returns null if the build is running.

It returns correct ZonedDateTime once the build has finished

Answer (score 0):

If I run a REST call via browser with guest authentication:

`GET /app/rest/builds/id:[id_of_started_but_not_finished_yet_build]`

TeamCity returns incomplete XML response like first 1063 characters
and HTTP response code is 403

It works fine if I authenticate as a non guest user

so the workaround is to use `httpAuth()` instead of `guestAuth()`

```
TeamCityInstanceFactory.httpAuth("my_teamcity_server_url", "user", "password")
.build(new BuildId("id_of_started_but_not_finished_yet_build"))
.getStartDateTime()
```

Comment: if HTTP 403 Forbidden has security on mind, the response body should not contain any data. Trimming response to first 1063 chars breaks the xml structure.

Comment: The response with partial xml I get on TeamCity Enterprise 2022.04.4 (build 108763). 
On latest TeamCity Professional 2022.04.4 (build 108763) docker image
the response seems to be correct:

Responding with error, status code: 403 (Forbidden).
Details: jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.auth.AccessDeniedException: You do not have "View build runtime parameters and data" permission in project with internal id: project1
Access denied. Check the user has enough permissions to perform the operation.

Comment: the server response depends on data size.
you may get either exception or partial response.
I registered security issue for this:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-77745/REST-API-View-build-runtime-parameters-and-data-permission-broken-for-long-content
(you may have no permission to see it)